# Angular Material Table and IE11 not setting columns correctly

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular-material, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to make my app compatible with IE11, but in my mat table, the columns are all squished, as shown in the attached pic.
Here is my scss code to set its appearance:
How can I make this work with IE11?
Thanks!

```css
table{
    width: 100%;  
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #00000029;
    table-layout: fixed;
    
}
 //First column and header
.mat-header-cell:first-child,.mat-cell:first-child{
  flex:5%;
  z-index: 1;
}
//Second column and header
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(2),.mat-cell:nth-child(2){
  flex:45%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(3),.mat-cell:nth-child(3){
  flex:5%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(3){
  margin-left: 3px;
}

//Last column and header
.mat-header-cell:last-child,.mat-cell:last-child{
  flex:5%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#headerRow{
  background-color:#6E6E6E ;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
  height: 37px;
  
}
td.mat-cell{
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}

th.mat-header-cell{
    border-bottom-style: none;
    font: Bold 16px/16px "adobe-clean", sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest also try to provide the Mat table design code. Only the SCSS code will not help to find the cause of the issue. If you provide the sample design code then we can try to make a test with it and try to find the cause of the issue and we can try to provide suggestions for it.

Answer (score 1):

IE does not like the "table-cell" property for display. this is how i fixed it.

```
mat-table {
  display: table;
  min-width: 94vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  mat-header-cell,
  mat-cell {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    white-space: unset !important;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    width: max-content;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2px;
    //display: table-cell;
    min-height: 0;
  }
}
```